# More than a few hundred NFTs?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, nft

Is is possible to use Tezos to make more than 100ish NFTS? Using [this template](https://smartpy.io/ide?template=FA2.py) it seems that if over ~100 NFTs are minted, the contracts storage runs out. This is also concerning because it seems if someone transfers an nft to and from someone ~1000 times it will also fill up the contract storage. Is Tezos fundamentally limited by these contract storage constants? If not, how would I modify this contract to allow for potentially unlimited number of NFTS and transfers?

Answer (score 1):

That is not true, the contract by default allows you to mint as many tokens as you want without the risk to get gas locked.

You probably set the flag `assume_consecutive_token_ids` to **false** which creates a set with all created token ids. The default behavior uses a **nat** which indicates the number of existent tokens.

Templates are not supposed to serve every single use case, users should always use them as references and adapt them to their needs.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. If you add a lot of data to a smart contract you might need to manually raise the Adjust storage limit. This fixes the `Status: backtracked`

Answer (score 1):

Contract storage is not bounded, only the storage size difference for each operation is bounded. If you want to go beyond the storage size difference limit you need to either clear some data from the contract storage or split the operation into several ones.